# Combinations of indistinguishable objects in containers restricted to given conditions

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to al locate $50$ indistinguishable objects into $10$ distinguishable containers so that there at least $10$ objects in at least one of them?

What's troubling me is the condition on the amount of objects in that (at least) one container. At first I thought I can count all the combinations by the following formula: $$10 \sum_\limits{k=0}^{40} \binom{40+9-k}{9}$$ that is I put $10+k$ objects in one of the $10$ containers and then divide the rest, but then I count some combinations more than once.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean at least $10$ objects in a particular container or at least $10$ objects in one of the ten containers?

Comment: at least $10$ in one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-place $10$ in $1\;$thru $\;5$ containers, distribute the balance freely, and apply inclusion-exclusion

$\binom{10}1\binom{49}{9} - \binom{10}2\binom{39}{9} + \binom{10}{3}\binom{29}9 -\binom{10}{4}\binom{19}{9} + \binom{10}{5}\binom99$

Comment: But I want 10 objects in at least one of them, not in every one of them

Comment: Adjusted. Idk why the site is giving problems.